# if 0 show " ", if <500 show "B", if >500 show "R"

Tags: ms-access-2010

I'm working on a query in Access 2010 and need help.

- If the value is =0 I want it to show as blank,
- if the value is <500 I want it to show as "B",
- if the value is >500 I want it to show as "R"

Comment: What do you want it to say if the value = 500?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try:

```
IIf([value] = 0, "", IIf([value] < 500, "B", "R"))
```

`IIf` is a function that returns on of two values depending on the outcome of the conditional.

Comment: Thanks for such a fast answer! I knew about the IIF statement but I had no idea I could combine it twice like that. Now it works